# counting Numbers of sets with given specifications

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a set, , consisting of integers. The set is beautiful if at least one of the following conditions holds true for every X in set S:

X-1 is in S or X+1 is in S

For example, { 1 ,2 ,50 , 51} is beautiful but {1 ,4,5,6} is not beautiful. Given two integers N and K , and , can you find the number of different beautiful sets of size K that can be created using integers from 1 to N . take mod of answer with 1000000007

My sol : taking sets such that first m consecutive and next k-m consecutive after leaving some elements. which comes up as

res =n-k+1 + max(0,(k-3)) * sumOfIntegers(n-k);

However i am getting WA please help

Comment: I'm a little surprised that after a Google search, this doesn't seem to be a Project Euler problem.

Comment: Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation on how to properly format mathematics.

Comment: @Patrick: The requirement to present the answer mod $10^9+7$ is a dead giveaway that it’s probably from a programming competition.